# When does it make sense to use an abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

I'm transitioning from c to c++ and of course, OOP which is proving more difficult than expected.  The difficulty isn't understanding the core mechanics of classes and inheritance, but how to use it.  I've read book on design patterns but they only show the techniques and paint a vague picture of why the techniques should be used. I am really struggling to find a use for abstract classes. Take the code below for example.

```
class baseClass {
public:
    virtual void func1() = 0;
    virtual void func2() = 0;
};
class inhClass1 : baseClass {
public:
    void func1();
    void func2();
};
class inhClass2 : baseClass{
public:
    void func1();
    void func2();
};
int main() {}
```

I frequently see abstract classes set up like this in design books. I understand that with this configuration the inherited classes have access to the public members of the base class.  I understand that virtual functions are placeholders for the inherited classes.  The problem is I still don't understand how this is useful.  I'm trying to compare it to overloading functions and I'm just not seeing a practical use.

What I would really like is for someone to give the simplest example possible to illustrate why an abstract class is actually useful and the best solution for a situation. Don't get me wrong. I'm not saying there isn't a good answer. I just don't understand how to use them correctly.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of an interface?

Comment: Not entirely. I have read about them, but I really don't understand them.   From what I understand, the base class would be an interface. At least in this example.

Comment: There is no abstract class in the shown code.

Comment: Wow, now I'm really confused.

Comment: @mreff555 ABCs can be used to create interfaces in c++, since c++ didn't have explicit interfaces like Java. Long story short, if a class implements an interface, you know it has a certain functionality. ABCs allow you to have an interface that also contains code that can be shared by implementers.

Comment: So, why is the code above not an abstract class?

Comment: C++ does not have an interface keyword, but a class with all virtual methods and a pure virtual destructor is an interface.

Comment: I think that Sam is saying that you did not declare the class itself as virtual.

Comment: Interesting.  As much as I have been reading about abstract classes, I'm not sure I have seen that done.  Is that what is required for an abstract class, or does it have something to do that these are not "pure virtual functions"? I've seen on more than one occasion that this is is what makes a class abstract.

Comment: Ok, I modified my code so it is now an official abstract class.  I guess an extension of my original question would be, why would code in this format be any more efficient than two concrete classes without the abstract class.  Even if there were a dozen or more of these inherited classes, I don't understand how the abstraction improves the situation.

Comment: Still not an abstract class: no pure virtual destructor.  If you want an example of how interfaces can help, go look at Java's package for interfacing with relational databases.  It's impossible to know every implementation, so Sun created a set of interfaces to specify what had to be done without spelling out how to do it.  Vendors write implementation classes that conform to the interface for their product.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading the article now. BTW duffymo.  As the code is above, the gnu compiler refers to this as an abstract class.  What are the additional requirements? a pure virtual constructor/destructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abstract classes and interfaces both allow you to define a method signature that subclasses are expected to implement: name, parameters, exceptions, and return type.

Abstract classes can provide a default implementation *if* a sensible one exists.  This means that subclasses do not have to implement such a method; they can use the default implementation if they choose to.

Interfaces do not have such an option.  Classes that implement an interface are *required* to implement all its methods.

In Java the distinction is clear because the language includes the keyword `interface`.

C++ interfaces are classes that have all `virtual` methods plus a pure virtual destructor.

Abstract classes and interfaces are used when you want to decouple interface from implementation.  They're useful when you know you'll have several implementations to choose from or when you're writing a framework that lets clients plug in their own implementation.  The interface provides a contract that clients are expected to adhere to.

Comment: Note that this is a C++ question, not a Java one.

Comment: I know.  The idea of an interface transcends Java and C++.  In C++, it would be a class with all virtual methods and a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: Yes, as long as it is understood as the general concept and not a keyword. Just wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

One use of abstract classes is to be able to easily switch between different concrete implementations with minimal changes to your code. You do this by declaring a reference variable to the base class type. The only mention of the derived class is during creation. All other code uses the base class reference.

Comment: "Coding to an interface" instead of a specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are used to provide abstract representation of some concept you want to implement hiding the details.

For example let's say I want to implement File system interface :-

At abstract level what I can think of?

```
class FileSystemInterface
{
    virtual void openFile();
    virtual void closeFile();
    virtual void readFile();
    virtual void writeFile();
};
```

At this point of time I am not thinking of anything specific like how they will be handled in windows or linux rather I am focusing on some abstract idea.

Comment: This seems useful, and I'm sorry if this question seems ignorant but I started out with c99 and overloading functions. You still need to write the other classes. What is better about writing the additional abstract class?

Comment: Main benefit is you will be programming to an interface rather than implementation. So, later you can change implementation in any way you wish without affecting your client.